# Matlab read last entry of vector unequal to zero

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there a way to read the last entry of a matlab vector that is not zero?
I have a matrix 1x20 and write values on it dependent on the iterations of a while loop in it. I tried creating a matrix the size of the counter of the while loop but that doesn't work as the zero command overwrites it in every loop.

Thanks for any proposals

Comment: Maybe post some simple example code which shows what's going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`find` function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) looks for nonzero entries in an array, and it takes options that let you say "just one, looking from the end".

Comment: Note: find returns indices, not numbers, so if you do `idx = find(myvector,1,'last');` you'll need to do `lastnonzeronumber = myvector(idx);` if you're looking for the number.

Comment: @HughNolan Or `[~, ~, val] = find(myVector,1,'last')` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to read the last entry of a matlab vector that is not
>   zero?

```
a = [3 5 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 2 3 6 0 0 0 0]  
ind = find(a ~= 0, 1, 'last')
val = a(ind)
```